# Shopify, Liquid, Alpine JS, Ajax can't redirect to cart after firing addToCart

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid, alpine.js

Can't figure out why after my ajax addToCart function is called not being redirected to cart?

The product is getting into cart as expected.

I have tried preventingDefault and not preventing.

Here is what response and formData look like in image below.

[image]

Here is my product form.

```
      <div class="tw-p-8">
          <h2 class="tw-mb-4 tw-text-white">Your Selections</h2>
          {% assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id %}
          {%- form 'product',
            product,
            id: product_form_id,
            class: 'form',
            novalidate: 'novalidate',
            data-type: 'add-to-cart-form'
          -%}
            <input
              type="hidden"
              name="id"
              value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
              disabled
            >
            <div class="product-form__buttons">
              <button
                type="submit"
                @click.prevent="addToCart(items, box_size)"
                :class="full_box ? 'tw-bg-ctaColor' : ''"
                class="tw-bg-white tw-text-brandText tw-flex tw-justify-center tw-py-4 tw-px-6 tw-rounded-full tw-font-bold"
              >
                <p class="" x-show="!full_box">
                  <span x-text="items_selected" class="tw-mr-2"></span><span class="tw-mr-2">of</span
                  ><span class="tw-font-bold" x-text="box_size"></span><span class="tw-ml-2">Selected</span>
                </p>
                <p x-show="full_box" class="">Add to cart</p>
              </button>
            </div>
          {%- endform -%}
        </div>
```

Here is my addToCart function.

```
    <div
        x-data="
          {
            addToCart(items, size){
             const price = getBoxPrice(size)
             console.log({price})
             let itemsToAdd = items.map((item) => {
               return item['title'];
             })

             let selectedItems = itemsToAdd.toString()
             console.log({selectedItems})
             console.log({itemsToAdd})
              let formData = {
              'items': [{
                'id': 44202123100470,
                'quantity': 1,
                'properties': {
                  'Box Items': selectedItems,
                  }
                }]
              };
              console.log({formData})
              fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData)
              })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((data) => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
              });
              reset()
            }
          }
        "
        class="tw-mt-12 tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-p-auto tw-bg-brandText tw-opacity-80"
      > ....</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to use the [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) add location.href="/cart" in the success promise of the Ajax call.

```
             fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData)
              })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((data) => {
               location.href = '/cart';
                console.log('Success:', data);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
              });
```